# Failed to load resource admin-ajax.php

Tags: wp-admin

I'm still new to WordPress. I have been encountering `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` error and its pointing it in `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. I have check the folder and `admin-ajax.php` is there. I also tried calling `admin-ajax.php` using `network_admin_url()` instead of `admin_url()`. But I still keeps on having that error. Is there anyway to solve it? Thank you very much for your help.

Here is the sample code

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    cache: false,
    data: { action: 'getInfo' },
    success: function(data) {
      mIDs= mDisplay(data);
    }
  }).done(function( msg ) {

  });
```

Comment: Where is this JS being written? In a template? JS file? Functions file?

Comment: @JacobPeattie it is in my header.php, in a template

Comment: Please check on page source , if there is perfect url as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contact the hosting provider regarding it. They advise me to fix the .htaccess which causing the error.

Comment: Hi @natsumiyu How did you solve this, please?

Answer (score 0):

finally the problem was that the hosting provider had blocked the admin-ajax.php file saying that this file was receiving too many request, and requests to this file bypasses cache , hence it was causing problems on server :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. How will I know if its the hosting provider fault?

Comment: You'd need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're writing javascript with in php file.

`var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';`
You're going to save the return value in `ajaxurl` variable, so you shouldn't `echo` it.

For external js files, you have to use `wp_localize_script` to pass ajaxurl to js file

Answer (score 0):

Check if your host has ModSecurity enabled, disable it and give it a try.

worked for me